# Test jax.pmap before deploying on multi-device hardware

Tags: multiprocessing, tpu, jax, pmap

My question is fairly simple:

I am coding on a single-device small laptop and I am using `jax.pmap` because my code will run on multiple TPUs. I would like to "fake" having multiple devices to test my code and try different things.

Is there any way to do it? I doubt the solution will be within Jax though. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can spoof multiple XLA devices backed by a single device by setting the following environment variable:

```
$ set XLA_FLAGS="--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=8"
```

In Python, you could do it like this

```py
# Note: must set this env variable before jax is imported
import os
os.environ['XLA_FLAGS'] = "--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=8"

import jax

print(jax.devices())
# [CpuDevice(id=0), CpuDevice(id=1), CpuDevice(id=2), CpuDevice(id=3),
#  CpuDevice(id=4), CpuDevice(id=5), CpuDevice(id=6), CpuDevice(id=7)]

import jax.numpy as jnp
out = jax.pmap(lambda x: x ** 2)(jnp.arange(8))
print(out)
# [ 0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49]
```

Note that when a only a single physical device is present, all the "devices" here will be backed by the same threadpool. This will not improve performance of the code, but it can be useful for testing the semantics of parallel implementations on a single-device machine.